# Why I got "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" here?

Tags: java, cors

In my frontend application when I make a call to the backend I get an error related to CORS. If I make this call from postman, I have no problems.

[image: The error]

JWT Interceptor

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthService } from './Services/auth.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class JwtInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(public auth: AuthService) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    request = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        Authorization: 'Bearer REDACTED'
      }
    });

    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

Call

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/demo-controller/ok').subscribe()
```

And from backend:
Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/demo-controller")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http:localhost:4200/", allowedHeaders = "*")
public class DemoController {

    @GetMapping("/ok")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getOk() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("OK");
    }
}
```

Security configuration:

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Application configuration for cors:

```
 @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> corsFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> bean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(new CorsFilter());
        bean.setOrder(0);
        return bean;
    }
```

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final JwtService jwtService;
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            @NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
            @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
            @NonNull FilterChain filterChain
    ) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            return;
        }
        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        final String jwt;
        final String userEmail;
        System.out.println(authHeader);
        if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")){
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
        jwt = authHeader.substring(7);
        userEmail = jwtService.extractUsername(jwt);
        if(userEmail != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null){
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userEmail);
            if (jwtService.isTokenValid(jwt, userDetails)){
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails,
                        null,
                        userDetails.getAuthorities()
                );
                authToken.setDetails(
                        new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request)
                );
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
    }
}
```

Cors filter:

```
public class CorsFilter implements Filter, jakarta.servlet.Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        HttpServletRequest  req = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Host, Referer, Connection, User-Agent, Authorization, sw-useragent, sw-version");
        System.out.println(req.getMethod());
        if (req.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
            System.out.println(req);
            res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            return;
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

    public void destroy() {}

    @Override
    public boolean isLoggable(LogRecord record) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

When I make the get request from backend I got the error, and also I saw this:

There are two calls, one is OPTIONS:
[image: There are two calls, one is OPTIONS]

The bearer is in header but the call doesn't reach the backend
[image: The bearer is in header but the call doesn't reach the backend]

I tried several solutions but none worked.